# Localizable.strings appear red in Xcode 4.6.3 Copy Bundle Resources Tab?

Tags: ios, xcode

Hello I have different Localizable.strings in my app. I have also two targets.
I noticed that in the Build phases Copy Bundle Resources Tab two from the three Localizable.strings files appear to be red. even if I delete and add them again? what does this mean?

If I deploy the app the languages work but I have a problem with getting the default language to work. So I suspect the "red" to mean something bad?

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for the red Localizable.strings or other Localization-files which can't be copied in the 'Copy Bundle Resources' can be the setting for the 'Localization native development region' in your Target settings.

This region should be added to the 'Localizations' of your project.

I.e. if the 'Localization native development region' is 'en', then 'English' should be added as Localization in your project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check your language codes against this list : http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php

Comment: well my folders are named en.lproj fr.lproj and de.lproj and the files are all named Localizable.strings so I do not see a problem here

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry about the red color. check changing your iphone language and see if your app shows the correct language if localized for that language. in my projects, i can see that the localization files are red in copy bundle resource, but it works. there might be something wrong with xcode. i see that since xcode 4.x with different projects.